# api instagram php

Tags: php, api, instagram-api

Работаю с api instagram в php, так вот мне нужно получить данные о пользователе. В оф. документации instagram > (https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/), есть такая строка:

```
This is a sample request:
       curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
        -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
        -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
        -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
        -F 'code=CODE' \
        https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Так вот, как я понял, это указано как пример, для получения токена (поправьте если не так), посмотрел видеоролики на php, и там пишут так:

```
public function getAccessTokenAndUserDetails($code) {
        $postFields = array(
            "client_id" => $this->clientID,
            "client_secret" => $this->clientSecret,
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "redirect_uri" => $this->redirectURI,
            "code" => $code
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
```

Ну уже и через функцию получаем к ней доступ:
 
`$data = $Instagram->getAccessTokenAndUserDetails($_GET['code']); print_r($data);` 
 Так вот, вопрос, у меня что-то не работает, то есть json запрос не отображается, показывает null(через var_dump). В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Что-то в коде вообще обработки ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном вами примере при возврате значения в методе getAccessTokenAndUserDetails вы используете json_decode(). Он возвращает null в двух случаях:

1. Не смог распарсить ответ (некорректный json или вообще не json) - наиболее вероятно
2. Уровень вложенности json - массива превышает установленную глубину рекурсии - маловероятно.

Таким образом, проверьте, какой ответ возвращает вам curl-запрос, действительно ли он является валидным json:

```
public function getAccessTokenAndUserDetails($code) {
        $postFields = array(
            "client_id" => $this->clientID,
            "client_secret" => $this->clientSecret,
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "redirect_uri" => $this->redirectURI,
            "code" => $code
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($response); // смотрим, что вернул curl
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
```